# Продавать со склада - продавать из хозяйства?

Tags: употребление-слов

Чувствую, что сочетание "продавать/покупать ИЗ хозяйства" - неправильное, но как объяснить, не знаю, хотя сама филолог (должно быть стыдно)... Всегда исправляю на "продам/куплю В хозяйстве".
Спасибо объяснившему!

Answer (score 1):

> "продавать/покупать ИЗ хозяйства"

Не вижу ничего принципиально неправильного. 
Возможно, Вы о конкретном значении "покупать - где?" - тогда естественно, в хозяйстве. 
Но если тут подчеркивается место не покупки, а происхождения товара ("Суп в кастрюльке прямо на пароходе приехал из Парижа") то почему и нет?
А можно узнать, в связи с чем у Вас подобное встречается? Почему так часто упоминается это самое хозяйство?

//============

Ну будет ли он от того более "грамотным" - это большой вопрос.
Но если это обычное купи-продай, то я вообще не вижу причин для постоянного упоминания этого хозяйства.
Впрочем, давайте подумаем.
Если за этим стоит "от производителя", то так и надо писать. 
Если речь идет о самовывозе (пункт осуществления продажи - хозяйство), то, пожалуй что - ИЗ, но лучше всего написать явно.
Ну а если это вообще ничего не несет, то удалять. 
Т.е. при всей грамматической правильности "в хозяйстве" я не вижу большого смысла в его постоянном упоминании. "Из хозяйства", получается, более нагружено смыслом...

Надо бы попытать тех, кто "в теме", какой смысл они вкладывают в это "из хойзяйства". Точно ли "где"?

Comment: Мне приходится модерировать объявления на сайте, связанном с сельским хозяйством, и это клише "куплю/продам ИЗ хозяйства" меня уже достало, т.к. речь идет о том, покупать/продавать - где? Вот я и правлю - стараюсь, чтобы мой сайт был, по возможности, грамотным - на фоне разгула безграмотности во всех сферах...

Comment: дополнил ответ.